# How to show the node delete tab and put a view in it?

Tags: 7, views, routes

I would like to show a '**Delete**' tab near the 'View' and 'Edit' tabs in the node page and insert a custom warning message and a view in it. If I create a view tab page with path /node/%/delete it works fine, but the submit button is missing and I can't figure out how to add it. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By creating a view with path /node/%/delete, you have completely replaced the existing page (the delete confirmation form). According to Drupal logic, this is normal behavior.

What I would do is:

1) Do not use the *page* display of your view, but add a *block* display to the view. Add your message as view header. Place that block above the main page content and restrict it to the node/*/delete path.

2) Create custom module, implementing [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) with one line of  code ([credits](http://groups.drupal.org/node/26051)):

```
function MODULENAME_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['context'] = MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE;
}
```

Of course you need to replace `MODULENAME` with the actual name of your module.

Comment: Instead of node/%/delete I used node/*/delete. Perfect. Many Thanks.

Comment: You are completely right, my mistake. The `%` placeholder is used in hook_menu(_alter) while the `*` placeholder is used in block visibility settings. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hook_menu_alter to add the tab and hook_form_alter to add your message to the page. You can then create a view block and add the block to the content area for the node/*/delete path.
Use the following code and replace MYMODULE with your module name:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['context'] = MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id=='node_delete_confirm'){
    drupal_set_message('my msessage');
  }
}
```